# How to access files from other network using credentials in window service

Tags: c#

I've created a window service application where it read files from other networks then save it to my database every 1 minute. I have been provided a username and password to access the file from the other network. Unfortunately, I don't know how to how to access the file with network username and. password Can you show me how. Thank you.

I know how to provide the path of the file from app.config

> appSettings
>
> > add key="filepath" value="\111.111.1.11\dummyfolder\"

And access it to my code by this:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filepath"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can be easier?

```
class AuthHelper
    {
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
            String lpszDomain,
            String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        public static WindowsIdentity GetWindowsIdentityForUser(String userName, String password, String domain)
        {
            WindowsIdentity result = null;

            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (RevertToSelf())
                if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        result = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        if (result != null) return result;
                    }

            if (token != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And then just:

```
var identity = AuthHelper.GetWindowsIdentityForUser("other user", "password", "domain");
            using (var context = identity.Impersonate())
            {
                //do whatever you want as "other user"
            }
```

Comment: I am encountering an error with this (var context = identity.Impersonate()) because it's returning null.

Comment: Hi! I'm not exactly sure but this function: GetWindowsIdentityForUser() returns null, that's why i'm encountering error with this: using (var context = identity.Impersonate())

Comment: If result is null then something goes wrong (incorrect login/password?), check what's going on inside GetWindowsIdentityForUser

Comment: Already resolved this issue. The value of LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE is incorrect. Thank you.